How to specify separate script inside HTML export template?
I have some script modules (index.js) that I need to include to HTML export template.
How to do it right? I couldn't find any solution. After Godot starts local web server it can't find these scripts. As I understand it doesn't see them and doesn't do anything with them.
As if you have to insert scripts content right inside .html, but I have dynamic imports and the point is to load only what I need.
Thank you in advance!
HTML template:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <script src="index.js" type="module"></script> <!-- not found on local Godot server-->
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script src="$GODOT_URL"></script>
    <script>
        var engine = new Engine($GODOT_CONFIG);
        engine.startGame();
    </script>
</body>
</html>

